# why Object.GetType() is not virtual?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

code sample taken from MSDN

```
public class Test {
public static void Main() {
  MyBaseClass myBase = new MyBaseClass();
  MyDerivedClass myDerived = new MyDerivedClass();
  object o = myDerived;
  MyBaseClass b = myDerived;

  Console.WriteLine("mybase: Type is {0}", myBase.GetType());
  Console.WriteLine("myDerived: Type is {0}", myDerived.GetType());
  Console.WriteLine("object o = myDerived: Type is {0}", o.GetType());
  Console.WriteLine("MyBaseClass b = myDerived: Type is {0}", b.GetType());   }}

/*
This code produces the following output.
mybase: Type is MyBaseClass
myDerived: Type is MyDerivedClass
object o = myDerived: Type is MyDerivedClass
MyBaseClass b = myDerived: Type is MyDerivedClass 
*/
```

So would it be logical to make GetType() virtual at least it works as virtual? Can anybody explaine that?
And other question Is any other methods in NET framework which have behaviour alike GetType?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

because .Net framework does not want you to override the GetType() method and `spoof` about the type.

assume you can override the method what else would you want it to do other than returning the type of the instance. and when you override the method for each of your classes to return the type of the instance, won't you violate DRY then.

Comment: yes. you're right. but you may overload this public method in derived class ))

Comment: @Arseny: Then it's not the same as GetType() as defined on the Object type.

Comment: Well, there are exceptions, though. One of these is dynamic proxying. When you call GetType() of a dynamic proxied class or interface, you will get "ClassNameProxy" as return type. Here it would make sense to override the GetType() method. However I see your point and this could be done adding a specific method (let's say GetImplentationType) on the class, interface or base class.

Comment: Well, It looks like I have to correct myself. I tried to do what I wrote above. I created 2 classes implementing an interface exposing one GetImplementingType method  and dynamic proxied them. In each implementation the method returned a typeof(ClassType) value.

Well, when caling the method at runtime, it returned NULL. Now I'm trying with an abstract base class.

Answer (score 4):

While its true that you cannot override the object.GetType() method, you can use "new" to overload it completely, thereby spoofing another known type.  This is interesting, however, I haven't figured out how to create an instance of the "Type" object from scratch, so the example below pretends to be another type.

```
public class NotAString
{
    private string m_RealString = string.Empty;
    public new Type GetType()
    {
        return m_RealString.GetType();
    }
}
```

After creating an instance of this, (new NotAString()).GetType(), will indeed return the type for a string.

Comment: By almost anything that looks at `GetType` has an instance of `object`, or at the very least some base type that they control or can reason about.  If you already have an instance of the most derived type then there is no need to call `GetType` on it.  The point is as long as someone uses `GetType` on an `object` they can be sure it's the system's implementation, not any other custom definition.

Answer (score 3):

GetType returns the actual Type of the object. This allows us to know what object we really got passed to 'our' function. Many methods of the framework need this to determine their own functionality - in most cases to get the Attributes of this class.
If the Framework would loose the possibility to determine the real type of an object, *the object would loose this type* as well.

If you like to know the type used within your method scope - the type you declared or was picked by the compiler - you can add a pretty simple extension method:

```
public static Type GetCurrentType<T>(this T obj)
{
    return typeof(T);
}

public static void Main()
{
  MyBaseClass myBase = new MyBaseClass();
  MyDerivedClass myDerived = new MyDerivedClass();
  object o = myDerived;
  MyBaseClass b = myDerived;

  Console.WriteLine("mybase: Type is {0}", myBase.GetCurrentType());
  Console.WriteLine("myDerived: Type is {0}", myDerived.GetCurrentType());
  Console.WriteLine("object o = myDerived: Type is {0}", o.GetCurrentType());
  Console.WriteLine("MyBaseClass b = myDerived: Type is {0}", b.GetCurrentType());
}

/*
This code produces the following output.
mybase: Type is ValidatorTest.MyBaseClass
myDerived: Type is ValidatorTest.MyDerivedClass
object o = myDerived: Type is System.Object
MyBaseClass b = myDerived: Type is ValidatorTest.MyBaseClass
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

If `GetType()` was virtual, a class named `HumanBeing` can override it and return a Type object representing `Robot` which is called spoofing and preventing this is one of the main features of CLR called Type Safety.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Dr Snooze's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439863/3465697), in order to "create an instance of the "Type" object from scratch":

```
public class NotAString
{
    public new Type GetType()
    {
        return typeof(string);
    }
}
```