# C# class can not disguise to be another class because GetType method cannot be override

Tags: c#

there is a statement in the CLR via C# saying
in C#, one class cannot disguise to be another, because GetType is virutal and thus it cannot be override

but I think in C# we can still hide the parent implementation of GetType.

I must missed something

if I hide the base GetType implementation then I can disguise my class to be another class, is that correct?

**The key here is not whether GetType is virutal or not, the question is can we disguise one class to be another in C#**

Following is the NO.4 answer from the possible duplicate, so My question is more on this.
is this kind of disguise possible, if so, how can we say that we can prevent class type disguise in C# ? regardless of the GetType is virtual or not

> While its true that you cannot override the object.GetType() method,
>   you can use "new" to overload it completely, thereby spoofing another
>   known type. This is interesting, however, I haven't figured out how to
>   create an instance of the "Type" object from scratch, so the example
>   below pretends to be another type.
>
> ```
> public class NotAString {
>     private string m_RealString = string.Empty;
>     public new Type GetType()
>     {
>         return m_RealString.GetType();
>     } }
> ```
>
> After creating an instance of this, (new NotAString()).GetType(), will indeed return the type for a string.
>
> share|edit|flag answered Mar 15 at 18:39
>
> Dr Snooze 213
>          By almost anything that looks at GetType has an instance of object, or at the very least some base type that they control or can
>   reason about. If you already have an instance of the most derived type
>   then there is no need to call GetType on it. The point is as long as
>   someone uses GetType on an object they can be sure it's the system's
>   implementation, not any other custom definition. – Servy Mar 15 at
>   18:54 add comment

Comment: what are you trying to ask ?

Comment: GetType() is *not* virtual - so if your instance is used as object your custom implementation will never be called

Comment: possible duplicate of [why Object.GetType() is not virtual?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253329/why-object-gettype-is-not-virtual)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988781/what-does-gettype-return-on-an-instance-of-type/7990086#7990086

Comment: sorry for not being specific, I am not asking whether the method is virtual, not insterested in that, I asking by changing the implementation of this method, can I disguise my class to be another class @Turbot

Comment: @zinking the answer to that question goes hand in and with the method being virtual or not.

Comment: @BrokenGlass link has answer for you that you can't `spoof` about the type.

Comment: @Turbot this is what I want to discuss, and in the NO4 post definitely shows my intention, and it's possible

Comment: While perhaps an interesting academic question I cannot envision a design scenario wherein this would be a good thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question only has meaning when you define a context:
*Disguise from whom/what?*

There are several options:

1. Disguising so that **runtime** will interpret it as a different type:
   **Not possible** using this method. Runtime does not even call `GetType`.
2. Disguising so that **some other library** will interpret it as a different type:
   **Not possible** using this method. If the library takes `B` you can not pass your class `X`, if the library takes `object` it will not call your `GetType` as it is `new`, not `override`.
3. Disguising so that a **developer** may think it is some other type when debugging:
   **Possible** (if he does not notice your trick). Why, though?

Comment: I don't think these are all scenarios, I am just saying: the text in the book is not rigid as there is still this flaw.

Comment: For the point 3, I'd consider it's also seldom possible. Since with `SomeObject.GetType()` IntelliSense should always prompts `object.GetType()`; and for a `Type`, for example `typeof(int).GetType()` is `Type.GetType()`. Any class's `GetType()` been shown as `ThatClassName.GetType()` with IntelliSense would straight be aware of. Anyway, it's an interesting point.

Comment: @KenKin I think if you enter `x.GetType()` in `Immediate`, and `x` is a variable of type `X` (statically) that shadows `GetType`, you should get incorrect type.

Answer (score 4):

`GetType` is not virtual, otherwise it is supposed to be overriden. It's *extern*.

If you want to hide an implementation of the base class, you can use `new` modifier.

There're various ways to know the type of an object instance. The following example shows how easy this disguise can be debunked:

```
public static class TestClass {
    public static void TestMethod() {
        var x=new Pretended();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", x.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", (x as object).GetType());
    }
}

public partial class Pretended {
    public new Type GetType() {
        return typeof(int);
    }
}
```

output of `TestMethod`:

> System.Int32
>
> Pretended

In c#, *most*(note: not all of) types derives from `object`, that is, their ultimate base class is `object`. And because `GetType` is not overridable, the `base.GetType()` is always there. Any approach to know the type without invoking the *fake* implementation of `GetType()`, just exposes the real type.

Answer (score 2):

`GetType` method is not marked as `virtual`, therefore it cannot be overriden.
Hiding the implementation of the `GetType` is possible by using `new` keyword, but `base.GetType()` would still return the type correctly and it cannot be manipulated by the developer.